# html/css select option block display

Tags: html, css, select

Is there a way to `display: block;` using a dropdown box `option`, à la `select`?

Here is an example of what I am trying to do, something similar: tabs with radio buttons, instead with `select`.

```css
div.sheet-class-content {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
option.sheet-Class1:checked ~ div.sheet-Class1, select option.sheet-Class2:checked ~ div.sheet-Class2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<select class="sheet-dropdown" name="attr_FirstClass">
  <option class="sheet-class-content sheet-Class1" value="None">None</option>
  <option class="sheet-class-content sheet-Class2" value="Soldier">Soldier</option>
</select>
<div class="sheet-Class1"></div>
<div class="sheet-Class2">
  <br>
  <b>Rank:</b> <input class="sheet-mainstat" name="attr_SoldierRank" type="number" value="1"/>
  <b>Level:</b> <input class="sheet-mainstat" name="attr_SoldierLevel" type="number" value="1"/>
  <p>
</div>
```

So is this even possible to do?  I'm not super advanced at this, but it seems like it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically speaking, modifying `<option>` elements is finnicky and very difficult to do. This is because they are controlled by the OS, rather than the browser. You may get them to do one thing in one browser on one OS, but I can tell you it won't look the same in a different browser or on a different OS.

Some things you just flat out cannot change.

The only good solution is to use a library JS-based select box, or make one of your own.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put a `<div>` around the `<select>` and force it to span the whole width, unless you have a `float` on the `<select>`.